# The say Command is not Working in High Sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra

I recently upgraded my MacBook to High Sierra (from El Cap).  It appears I can no longer use the `say` command.  When I enter a simple command

```
$ say -v "Alex" "Test"
[...hangs...]

$ sudo say -v "Alex" "Test"
Password:
[...hangs...]
```

My laptop hangs.  Is this a known issue and are there known fixes?  If not, does anyone know what next steps I might take in diagnosing this problem?

Comment: What happens when you issue the same command without `sudo`? I'm sure you have your reasons for using it, but `say` doesn't require escalated privileges to work as intended.

Comment: I have High Sierra and the command works fine.  I tried removing quotes, removing sudo, and removing the -v but it always works (just in a different voice) without -v.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add what happens when you enter `say Test` and `say -v Alex Test` and what you get if you enter `say -v Fred Test`. The `sudo` is doing nothing but making it necessary for you to enter your password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bug?**

I could tell something was wrong because the Speech section of the Accessability pane in System Preferences was stuck loading voices and the voice sample play button also did not work. I killed some speech and audio-related processes with some luck.

I was also able to reproduce the hang by using the `-o` option of the terminal `say` command.

**Workaround without reboot:**

Try killing `speechsynthesisd` after finding it with

```
ps ax |grep speechsynthesisd
```

or just kill it this way:

```
kill `pgrep speechsynthesisd`
```

Comment: Or just `pkill speechsynthesisd  say`. (I've found it helpful to also kill any hanging `say` processes.)

Comment: Thank you! I somehow missed this answer originally, and this is a much better work around than a reboot.  I still don't know why speechsynthesisd is hanging when I try to `say` with an input and output file, but at least I can diagnose things without a full reboot!

Answer (score 1):

Is normal audio output working otherwise? Do you have an “atypical” audio output device?

Open the Speech/Narration system preferences pane, there may be some internal data that is “stuck” that could clear out by loading / saving preferences from that pane.

Comment: A system reboot "solved" my problem -- but next I'll definitely poke around the `Accessibility -> Speech` preference pane (I didn't see one named Speech/Narration)

Comment: The speech preferences pane hung for me as well. The `kill` statement worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case `say` was freezing when audio was muted on older mac mini. Once we increased a volume, the `say` started working again.