# MacOS Say Command Hangs Writing to a File

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

For many years I've been using the `say` command to read back essays I've written.  My workflow is

1. Use `say` to write out an `aiff` or `WAVE` file
2. Use an audio player like iTunes to playback the file, pausing and rewinding as needed

However, recently the `say` command started to hang when I used it with an input and output file.

```
$ ls -lh /tmp/md_to_sayfbfhyf.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alanstorm  wheel   5.8K Jan  5 08:59 /tmp/md_to_sayfbfhyf.txt

$ say -f /tmp/md_to_sayfbfhyf.txt -o output.aiff
```

This command will hang after writing a little over a MB to the aiff file.

```
$ ls -lh output.aiff
-rw-r--r--  1 alanstorm  staff   1.1M Jan  5 09:13 output.aiff
```

After that `say` will **always** hang unless I kill [speechsynthesisd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325862/the-say-command-is-not-working-in-high-sierra).

Also, this appears to be a problem with writing the output file -- running just

```
$ say -f /tmp/md_to_sayfbfhyf.txt
```

works without issue.

I'm on MacOS: 10.13.4 (High Sierra)

The command works with very small text files that contain a sentence or two -- but files with more than a few paragraphs of text hang.  I have not zeroed in on a specific file size or word count.

Comment: Does it fail for all input files or only for some? Does it fail independent of the directory the output gets written to?

Comment: Ah, which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @nohillside It fails independently of the directory used for reading/writing.  It does not fail for very small text file, but it does fail for files with more than a few paragraphs of text. I'm on the latest version of High Sierra. (question update to reflect this information)   Also -- thank you for your attention!

Comment: Yeah, just checked in Mojave, stops after writing 4K of audio. Hmm.

Comment: @nohillside That's extra odd -- I usually get around 1.1MB of audio information before it hangs.